# iPhone: Send E-Mail with Custom Content-Type

Tags: iphone, email, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios, ios4

I try to send an e-mail from an app with an custom Content-Type.

Any ideas how to do this?

So i like to change

"Content-Type":
"multipart/mixed; boundary=Apple-Mail-1--209662383" --> "application/pkcs7-mime; name=smime.p7m; smime-type=enveloped-data"

and 
"Content-Transfer-Encoding":

"7bit" --> "base64"

Comment: Is there some reason you can't just encode it as an attachment?

Comment: Yes i wan't to send encrypted smime attachment, and then the "Content-Type" must be "application/pkcs7-mime; name=smime.p7m; smime-type=enveloped-data" and the "Content-Transfer-Encoding" must be "base64"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used http://code.google.com/p/skpsmtpmessage/ for sending an custom mail with iOS.

Answer (score -1):

- (void)launchInAppMail {

  MFMailComposeViewController *controller = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];

  controller.mailComposeDelegate = self;

  [controller setSubject:@"In app email..."];

  NSMutableString *messageString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

  if (!(mNameField.text == nil || [mNameField.text isEqualToString:@""])) {

  ```
  [messageString appendFormat:@"Name: %@ \n",mNameField.text];
  ```

  }
  if (!(mPhoneNumberField.text == nil || [mPhoneNumberField.text isEqualToString:@""])) 
  {
      [messageString appendFormat:@"Phone Number: %@ \n",mPhoneNumberField.text];

  }

  if (!(mEmailField.text == nil || [mEmailField.text isEqualToString:@""])) {
      [messageString appendFormat:@"Email ID: %@ \n",mEmailField.text];
  }

  if (!(mTextView.text == nil || [mTextView.text isEqualToString:@""])) {

  ```
  [messageString appendFormat:@"Desription: %@ \n",mTextView.text];
  ```

  }

  if (!(mProblemNameButton.titleLabel.text == nil || [mProblemNameButton.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:@""])) {

  ```
  [messageString appendFormat:@"Problem Name:  %@ \n",mProblemNameButton.titleLabel.text];
  ```

  }

  [messageString appendFormat:@"Address: %@ \n", self.mAddress];

  if (self.coordinateLoc)

  ```
  [messageString appendFormat:@"Longitude: %f, Latitude: %f \n", self.coordinateLoc.coordinate.longitude, self.coordinateLoc.coordinate.latitude];
  ```

  [controller setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"service@emergencylocksmithleads.com"]];

  [controller setMessageBody:messageString isHTML:NO];

  [messageString release];

  if (mImageView.image != nil) {

  ```
  NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(mImageView.image, 1);


  [controller addAttachmentData:imageData mimeType:@"image/jpg" fileName:@"example.jpg"];
  ```

  }

  [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];

  [controller release];
  }

## pragma mark --------------------------------------------

## pragma mark MFMailComposeViewController delegate Methods

- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error {
  switch (result) {

      case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:

          NSLog(@"Mail send canceled.");

          /* 
           Execute your code for canceled event here ... 
           */

          break;

      case MFMailComposeResultSaved:

          NSLog(@"Mail saved.");

          /* 
           Execute your code for email saved event here ... 
           */
          break;
      case MFMailComposeResultSent: {
          UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Mail Sent" message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
          alert.tag = 1;
          alert.delegate = self;
          [alert show];
          [alert release];
          break;
      }
      case MFMailComposeResultFailed: {
          UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Mail Sending Failed" message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
          alert.tag = 2;
          alert.delegate = self;
          [alert show];
          [alert release];
          break;
      }
      default:
          break;
  }
  [controller dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
  }

Comment: Thats the code to send an mail, but not to change the "Content-Type" of the Mail...